# Search for multiple keywords related to separate columns on a single table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Imagine I have a table with the schema shown. Each of the columns represent a searchable collection that I would like to be picked up in the search. I am looking for a method that would derive the best match for the group of keywords entered into the search for by the user. Any example code would be highly appreciated.

```
    [JobID] [int] IDENTITY(1000000,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClassificationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubClassificationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JobTitle] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [WorkType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Position] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Keyword] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SalaryType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Could you show a few rows of sample data, and some keyword combinations, indicating which row(s) should be returned in each case? Right now the question is very vague and we have no idea exactly what type of search you are hoping to implement.

Comment: I don't much data since I'm in the process of designing an experimental DB to find out how this is done.  But you can take any job search website's scenario for instance where a user enters different search keywords and gets the closest job match.  I can make up some data for you but it might take a bit of some.  I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @Sam  Fulltext search will be a good option http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx and https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/full-text-indexing-workbench/